# Converting a string of numbers into an int vector c++

Tags: c++, string, vector, int

Is there a simple way to convert a string of numbers separated by spaces into a vector of ints or something that I can easily convert into a vector?

I am creating an input operator (>>) to make a binary tree using values input from command line. And this is the main that goes with it

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
stringstream stream;
stream << " 10" << " 11" << " 10" << " 2" << endl;
tree = new binary_tree();
stream >> *tree;
if (tree->inorder() != string("7 10 11")) //inorder() prints the tree in order
cout << "Test passed" << endl;
delete tree;

return 0;
}
```

The problem I am having is that while I can create and print the values that I need, I can't convert them and put them into a vector - for which I have a working defined method that creates a tree from the values.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, binary_tree &value)
{
vector<int> input_tree;
string readline;     
getline(in, readline);
cout << "(" << readline << ")" << endl; //prints correctly - (10 11 10 2)

    //where I need to insert insert values into vector

for(int i = 0; i < input_tree.size(); i++)
{
    insert(input_tree[i], value);    //inserts the values from a vector into a binary tree
}

return in;  
}
```

I have tried looping through the string and using stoi() on each character but it always errored whenever the spaces were causing errors.

Thanks for any help and sorry if I've missed any important information out.

Comment: You need to show exactly how you tried to convert the input, instead of leaving it out and replacing that code with the "//where I need to insert insert values into vector" comment. stackoverflow.com is not a code-writing service. Nobody will write your code for you. But, if you tried to parse the input into your `int` vector, and it's not working right, and you don't know what's wrong, then this would be a valid question. But "please write the code for me" is not a valid question.

Comment: The questions is if there is a way to convert a string to a vector<int> type, I'm not asking anyone to write my code I'm asking for a very specific thing while showing my code for reference.

Comment: Well, if that's your question, then the answer is "yes, there is a way".

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
vector<int> vec((istream_iterator<int>(in)), istream_iterator<int>());
```

This will read integers from `in` and insert them into `vec` all in one line.  It's a pretty canonical use of `istream_iterator` which is part of the standard library.  Then you don't need to read each line and parse it yourself.

If you want to read more about how this works, see here: [How does std::copy work with stream iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727125/how-does-stdcopy-work-with-stream-iterators)

As for why there appear to be an extra pair of parentheses around the first argument, that's because of the "most vexing parse": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse - just a silly quirk of C++ syntax.

Comment: I haven't tested it but surely that wouldn't work because in my example I'm using a stringstream and they are input as characters and not as int types?

Comment: @KL123: No, this is the entire point. The `istream_iterator<int>` is an interface to an `istream` (which a `stringstream` is) and performs the formatted extraction to `int` as it goes. Click on the link in the answer labelled "If you want to read more about how this works..."

Comment: This is hardly very expressive or clear code, though. As evidenced above. I'd write it in production code because it's the best solution C++ has to offer, but sadly that says more about C++ than much else.

Comment: Sth appears to be wrong either with your code or with my ability to copy-paste your code: http://ideone.com/t9ewIP

Comment: This is a common pitfall with parsing, due to C++'s complex syntax. That declaration of `vec` looks like a function declaration, and the compiler is trying to parse it, as such, and fails.

Comment: @gaazkam: Sorry, I've updated my answer with a small fix for that and an explanation of why the code needed another pair of parens.

Comment: @KL123: You're welcome.  If this answer solved your problem, you can "accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left side of the answer.  Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

A little easier to understand solution, I think (though less concise):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s= "4 5 6";
    stringstream ss(s);
    vector<int> v;

    int hlp;
    while(ss >> hlp)
    {
        v.push_back(hlp);
    }

    for(auto i: v)
        cout << i << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

You can use a `stringstream` just as you could use `cin`.

http://ideone.com/Y6UfuW