# Why does parse_config_file set failbit on a stream?

Tags: c++, stream, boost-program-options

This minimal program uses `boost::program_options` to parse a `stringstream`. Strangely, after parsing, the stream is not in a "good" state anymore and both failbit and eofbit are set.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/program_options/options_description.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/parsers.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/variables_map.hpp>

void test_stream(std::stringstream& s);

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  namespace po = boost::program_options;

  stringstream s;
  s << "seed=3" << '\n';
  test_stream(s);

  po::options_description desc("");
  desc.add_options()
    ("seed", po::value<int>());
  po::variables_map vm;
  po::store(po::parse_config_file(s, desc, true), vm);
  po::notify(vm);

  test_stream(s);

  return 0;
}

void test_stream(std::stringstream& s)
{
  using namespace std;

  if (s.good())
    {
      cout << "stream is good" << endl;
    }
  else
    {
      cout << "stream is not good" << endl;
      if (s.rdstate() & ios_base::badbit)
    cout << "badbit is set" << endl;
      if (s.rdstate() & ios_base::failbit)
    cout << "failbit is set" << endl;
      if (s.rdstate() & ios_base::eofbit)
    cout << "eofbit is set" << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
stream is good
stream is not good
failbit is set
eofbit is set
```

Although the eof condition is somehow expected, since presumably the parser has read the stream until EOF, why is also the failbit set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of the [`ios::eof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/) flag this might happen in certain cases:

> Operations that attempt to read at the End-of-File fail, and thus both the eofbit and the failbit end up set. This function can be used to check whether the failure is due to reaching the End-of-File or to some other reason.

Boost's parser uses `std::copy()` and an iterator on the stream to extract the options. As pointed out in [Jerry Coffin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16727354/2169513) to another question, the iterator reads the items from the sequence. After reading the last one the sequence's `eof` bit is set. When the iterator is incremented another time to get the end-of-stream iterator, which is the condition to leave the loop in `copy()`, it tries to read again and therefor also the stream's `fail` bit is set.