# Why std::istream_iterator<> with multiple copy_n() always writes firs value

Tags: c++, algorithm, istream-iterator

I tried to copy the input line into multiple vectors:

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <istream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::vector<int> v1, v2, v3;
  std::istringstream is ("1 2 3 4 5 6");
  std::istream_iterator<int> iit (is);
  std::copy_n(iit, 2, std::back_inserter(v1));
  std::copy_n(iit, 2, std::back_inserter(v2));
  std::copy(iit, std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(v3));
  std::ostream_iterator<int> oit(std::cout, ", ");
  std::copy(v1.begin(),v1.end(), oit);
  std::cout << "\n";
  std::copy(v2.begin(),v2.end(), oit);
  std::cout << "\n";
  std::copy(v3.begin(),v3.end(), oit);
  std::cout << "\n";
  return 0;

}
```

I assume this porgram output:

```
1, 2, 
3, 4, 
5, 6,
```

But I get this:

```
1, 2, 
1, 3, 
1, 4, 5, 6,
```

Why copy_n always insert 1 at the beginning of vectors?

Comment: If you read [the first sentence of `std::istream_iterator`'s description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator), combine it with the fact that the shown code passes the iterator ***by value*** to `std::copy_n`, and `std::copy_n` modifies the iterator, and then the shown code attempts to use the same, original value of the iterator, what conclusion can you draw from this?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You talking about: "The first object is read when the iterator is constructed"?  So I probably have to create a new istream_iterator every time I use a copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes down to a perhaps unintuitive fact of `istream_iterator`: it doesn't read when you dereference it, but instead [when you advance (or construct) it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator).

---

```
(x indicates a read)

Normal forward iterators:

   Data:            1   2   3   (EOF)
   
   Construction
   *it              x
   ++it
   *it                  x
   ++it
   *it                      x
   ++it                         (`it` is now the one-past-the-end iterator)
   Destruction

Stream iterators:

   Data:            1   2   3   (EOF)
   
   Construction     x
   *it
   ++it                 x
   *it
   ++it                     x
   *it
   ++it                         (`it` is now the one-past-the-end iterator)
   Destruction
```

We still expect the data to be provided to us via `*it`. So, to make this work, each bit of read data has to be temporarily stored in the iterator itself until we next do `*it`.

So, when you create `iit`, it's already pulling the first number out for you, `1`. That data is stored *in the iterator*. The next available data in the stream is `2`, which you then pull out using `copy_n`. In total that's two pieces of information delivered, out of a total of two that you asked for, so the first `copy_n` is done.

**The next time, you're using a copy of `iit` in the state it was in before the first `copy_n`. So, although the stream is ready to give you `3`, you still have a copy of that `1` "stuck" in your copied stream iterator.**

---

*Why* do stream iterators [work this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16727354/4386278)? Because you cannot detect EOF on a stream until you've tried and failed to obtain more data. If it didn't work this way, you'd have to do a dereference first to trigger this detection, and then what should the result be if we've reached EOF?

Furthermore, we expect that any dereference operation produces an immediate result; with a container that's a given, but with streams you could otherwise be blocking waiting for data to become available. It makes more logical sense to do this blocking on the construction/increment, instead, so that your iterator is always either valid, or it isn't.

---

If you sack off the copies, and construct a fresh stream iterator for each `copy_n`, you should be fine. Though I would generally recommend only using one stream iterator per stream, as that'll avoid anyone having to worry about this.

Comment: So when you recommend using one stream iterator per stream. Does that mean create a new iterator every time you use it in copy or anywhere else?

Comment: Actually yes that should be fine too. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @FedorGoncharov, a stream is like... a stream, a river. Once it's once a chunk of it passes, you will not see it again.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis For some categories of stream ;) But yes it is certainly helpful to think of them as flows of data, rather than as containers.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, I was referring to the only concept I know of as _stream_; what stream is re-iterable?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis `fstream`, `stringstream`, `strstream`, ...